# Why does VB not prevent the use of "Me" in field initialization like C# does with "this"?

Tags: c#, vb.net, clr

In VB you can have this:

```
Class One
    Private myTwo As Two = New Two(Me)
End Class

Class Two
    Sub New(withOne As One)

    End Sub
End Class
```

But in C#, you can't do this:

```
class One
{
    private Two myTwo = new Two(this);
}

class Two
{
    public Two(One withOne)
    {

    }
}
```

Because you get an error "Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context".

I found [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542518/c-sharp-this-operator-in-class-field-declaration) which quotes [the C# language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029) section 7.6.7:

> **7.6.7 This access**
>
> A this-access is permitted only in the block of an instance constructor, an instance
> method, or an instance accessor. ... (specifics omitted) ... Use of this in a primary-
> expression in a context other than the ones listed above is a compile-time error. In
> particular, it is not possible to refer to this in a static method, a static property
> accessor, or in a variable-initializer of a field declaration.

Furthermore, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381091/why-in-c-sharp-this-is-not-allowed-in-member-initializer-but-in-vb-net-me-is-al) covers it (although, in my option, does not sufficiently answer it), and Oblivious Sage's answer to my question here explains why -- because it's bug-preventing feature.

Why was this feature left out of VB?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about guessing why the language designer choose to make a particular decision.

Comment: @Servy -- Are you just making that reason up?

Comment: Could be a difference in order of operations when initializing objects. C# doesn't allow it because the `myTwo` initializer will run **before** the `One` being created is a valid object.

Comment: @roryap I used the custom close reason, yes.  I could have used "primarily opinion based" instead, and it would apply, but I choose to be more explicit for the sake of clarity.  A question in which all anyone can ever do is guess at what someone else is thinking is not on topic here.

Comment: @Servy -- That assumes that you are correct in saying "all anyone can ever do is guess at what someone else is thinking", which, I believe does not apply here.

Comment: @Servy This doesn't seem like a designer *intent* question. It seems like a "what design features make this work in one .NET language but not another?" question, which should be objectively answerable.

Comment: @roryap So you're assuming that the only people who are ever going to answer this question is the one language designer that made this design decision for C#, and that nobody else is allowed to answer it?

Comment: As the designers of the C# language, I doubt they would make an arbitrary choice like that and just hide it from posterity.

Comment: @Servy -- No, I'm not assuming that, because I doubt highly that one language designer has the power alone to make such a weighty decision.

Comment: @roryap They make millions of decisions when designing a language.  They look over many thousands of features considering which are worth implementing and which aren't.  While they may not go out of their way to hide all of the decisions, it's almost certainly not worth their time to go around finding every single question on every single site asking about them to go and answer them.

Comment: @roryap So the two or three people that might be able to answer it; same difference.  Are you honestly expecting one of those very few designers to come to your SO question and answer it for you?

Comment: @Servy -- You're thinking about this all wrong.

Comment: @roryap So then you're *not* expecting one of those few MS devs to come an answer your question?  If so, how do you expect whomever does answer it to know what they were thinking when they made this decision?  Or do you just think that it's not at all unreasonable to expect them to come to your question and answer it?

Comment: @ObliviousSage -- I disagree that that this is a dupe of that question, as it doesn't actually explain *why*, which is the crux of my question.  I think your answer, on the other hand, is perfect.

Comment: The question is certainly a duplicate. You are asking exactly the same thing `Why in C# this is not allowed in member initializer, but in VB.Net Me is allowed` (but more grammatically) Just because it got answers that didn't really answer it very well doesn't make it less so.

Comment: @MartinSmith -- Just because the title of that other question sounds like the title of my question does not mean they are the same.  "Don't judge a book by its cover".  And, just because the title of the other question contains the word "Why" and the OP selected an answer doesn't mean the question was answered sufficiently.  I'm stipulating that it was *not* answered sufficiently.  My question, however, *was* answered sufficiently, which, as the OP, is my prerogative to say.

Comment: Nope. Same question `My question is why is it legal in VB.Net and not C#?

Is this down to the compiler handling it differently? It seems weird that the two have different behaviours.` You can put a bounty to attract attention to questions that have already been asked but you feel do not have satisfactory answers.

Comment: @MartinSmith -- Show me where it discusses the fact that the constructor runs before the field initializers in VB but afterwards in C#?  That's the answer, and it's not provided anywhere in the answers to the other question.

Comment: The contents of the answers are irrelevant to whether or not *the question* is a duplicate or not. You asked the same question, got a somewhat better answer but I don't see the need to campaign to get the question unmarked as duplicate when it clearly is.

Comment: I note that the way the question is phrased "Why would this VB capability be explicitly denied in C#?" makes an unwarranted assumption that the "feature" is the *lack* of enforcement in VB. This assumption is unwarranted. If the question had been phrased "why was this bug-preventing feature of C# not added to VB.NET?" then it becomes a quite different question. C# and VB are similar but different languages with different semantics, different histories and different design criteria. Asking why there is a difference presumes that the difference was deliberately designed in.

Comment: @EricLippert -- "why was this bug-preventing feature of C# not added to VB.NET?" That assumes that I knew it was a bug-preventing feature, which I did not (hence my question).  It seems like "because it's a bug-preventing feature in C# that was not added to VB" would be a good *answer* to this question, especially if it included the reason why it's a bug-preventing feature in C#.  Since I still don't know the answer to that, could you please explain why?

Comment: @EricLippert -- Ahh, I just re-read Oblivious Sage's answer which explains it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602468/can-vb-net-be-forced-to-initialize-instance-variables-before-invoking-the-base-t), the difference is that constructors run *before* field initializers in VB.NET but *after* field initializers in C#. Therefore in VB.NET `Me` is a valid reference when the initializers run, but in C# `this` is not yet a valid reference when they run.

Per [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two.aspx) C# did it that way so that they could guarantee that readonly fields were always initialized before they could be referenced.

I didn't see it explicitly stated anywhere, but if I had to guess they noticed that flaw in VB.NET while C# was still being developed; they then felt that it was a big enough problem to be worth fixing in C# but not a big enough problem to make a breaking (and probably extensive) change to VB.NET.

Comment: Also, congrats on breaking quadruple digits...welcome to the club :)

Comment: Are you sure to not be between the one or two designers of vb.net? :-)

Comment: Good answer; to clarify slightly: that readonly fields are initialized before they are referenced is a desirable outcome, but the feature more generally protects against the whole class of errors caused by accessing members of an object before its constructor has run.